# Answers jump when hovering over "feedback"

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

When visiting the site as an anonymous user, hovering over the "feedback" link below an answer causes the following answers to jump down by about 5 pixels, and back up again when you move the mouse away.

Tested on Chrome 18, Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: The new design looks great, by the way :)

Comment: thanks, I'm looking into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put in a fix. It will be in the next production build.